# Regex to find links of hrefs and img src in HTML code

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I want to make a regex that will match links in HTML code.
This is example that will explain it better. Something like this:

```
<a href="I NEED THIS1">  <img src="I NEED THIS2">  </a>  <a href="I DONT
NEED THIS" title="something">  </a>   <a href="I NEED THIS3" title="blah">
<figure> <img src="I NEED THIS4" alt="">   </figure>  </a>
```

I tried something like this, but it matches *I DONT NEED THIS* instead of *I NEED THIS3*.

```
<a href="([^"]*)"\s*.*?<img src="(.*?)".*?\s*<\/a>
```

I tried to add negative lookahead with , but no matter where I put it, it is like I didn't add it at all. I am not sure I understand negative lookahead correct, but I tried to add (?!</a>).

I used regex that finds words near each other, and it works, but it is really not very elegant solution :) It finds href and img src when distance between is 0 and 7 words:

```
<a href="([^"]*)"\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,7}?<img src="(.*?)".*?\s*<\/a>
```

It will be used in Excel VBA and I was testing it on online regex tester websites.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: If you are reading HTML from the Web, you can use `InternetExplorer.Application` object. Then, you can parse the DOM easily, maybe easier than with the regex.

Comment: I need it to be done with regex and needs to be solved with one expression only. Two pass would be probably easier, but unfortunately not allowed to use it.

Comment: Ok, try [`<a\b[^<]*\bhref="([^"]*)"[^<]*>(?:(?!</?a\b[^<]*>)[\s\S])*<img\b[^<]*\bsrc="([^"]*)"`](https://regex101.com/r/jD5wP3/1).

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor. It looks like that this is the correct regex, it is working good for me. I will test it some more. Could you please try to explain this part of expresion:    (?:(?!<\/?a\b[^<]*>)[\s\S])*

Comment: Yeah, Wiktor, this definitely works. Thanks so much, you rock! :)

Comment: Good, it is up to you what to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use the MSHTML parser:

```
Dim odoc As Object: Set odoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
odoc.Open
odoc.Write htmlstr

For Each element In odoc.images
    MsgBox element.src
Next

For Each element In odoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    MsgBox element.href
Next
```

You may need to remove a leading `"about:"` prefix.

Comment: This is correct according the famous advice at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/122139 that has helped thousands.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution.

```
(href="([^"]+).*(?=img src))|(img src="([^"]*))
```

1. check for href="
2. return everything before the next " -> first group you're interested in
3. but only if there is img src following (positive lookahead)
4. check for img src="
5. return everything before the next " -> second group you're interested in

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yS9bB4/1

Comment: [`(href="([^"]+).*(?=img src))|(img src="([^"]*))`](https://regex101.com/r/lU4wT7/1) demo.